# How can i compile my C++ code to PowerPC Big-Endian

Tags: windows, gcc, powerpc

I want to to compile my C++ code into PowerPC ELF file which is Big Endian, i'm on windows and i already have GCC compiler installed with Eclipse, CodeBlocks, Visual Studio, RAD C++ Builder, and Qt, each one has specific use, can that be done with GCC? or is there any other compiler for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the compiler options here:

https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/RS_002f6000-and-PowerPC-Options.html

Comment: Hey Pete, i have saw that earlier but i couldn't know what to do, do i have to install GCC again with another configration?   if you could give me some tips or tutorial on how to do it on windows i will be appreciated.

Comment: You don't need to install GCC again.  In your IDE (or Makefile) you simply need to add the appropriate flags for what you are trying to do.

Comment: Be careful. If you've installed GCC for Windows, chances are it doesn't support the PowerPC. Each instance of GCC supports one processor family. You might want to look at something like my ELLCC. http://ellcc.org

Comment: Thank you Pete & Richard, i will take a look at ELLCC when i get home, much appreciated.

Comment: @RichardPennington Hi, I know it's a bit late but I just got back to this research. I downloaded the latest version of ELLCC for windows but I have no idea on how to use it, it's `471MB` in size and `1.75GB` after unpacking it, any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: @0x00 Hi, take a look at http://ellcc.org/blog/?p=18096 Change the "-target" option to "-target ppc-linux-eng". Use "ecc++.exe" to compile C++ programs in the same way.

Comment: It was something with the archive I had to rename it to .tgz after downloading because it was been renamed to another extension for some reason, I also had to extract it with cygwin tar command because  some binaries will not be extracted correctly if you use windows apps like 7Zip or winrar. Thank you for all your help man!